# Extremely lightweight text editor for OSX that just edits text

Tags: osx, text-editor

I'm looking for an extremely lightweight text editor that opens almost instantly and uses very little memory on OSX.

I have TextWrangler and Sublime Text, but both of those editors take more than *10* seconds to open. They're great when I want to work on a serious project, but often I want to write or open a small text file while working on a non-programming task. For these, I want to be able to open a text editor **within a split-second**, write my file, and close the editor again shortly thereafter.

Moreover, Sublime Text, in particular, can slow down my computer when I have several other resource-intensive apps open, such as Chrome and Eclipse.

I want a text editor that won't slow my computer down any more, even when I'm already running a lot of large programs on it.

I want a text editor that shows me my text in black on white as soon as I open the app.

To recap:

- very fast
- lightweight
- low memory

**No need for extra features such as syntax highlighting, I'm *not* going to use it for programming**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [TextEdit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextEdit). It is included with all OSX editions, and works perfectly:

- just edits text
- opens instantly (it does for me)
- low memory consumption
- lightweight
- shows text in black on white as soon as you open the app
- free (it's included ;p)

To save, by default as plain text files, check the following links:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/TA20406
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17433/can-textedit-save-as-plain-text

Comment: Have a look at [this article](http://hackerspace.lifehacker.com/the-text-editor-ive-been-searching-for-this-whole-time-1701123972) for a few tips on how to make TextEdit even better.

Comment: And "this article" link now 404s, but it is in the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150521031416/http://hackerspace.lifehacker.com/the-text-editor-ive-been-searching-for-this-whole-time-1701123972). Still helpful in 2021!

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, and the accepted answer is still a good one. But there are more options now.

Among these is **[CotEditor](https://coteditor.com/)**, which meets OP's requirements (**all** of them!) but also exceeds them for users who would like to personalize their editing environment just a little more than TextEdit allows for.

[image: CotEditor]

That's the editor as set up according to OP's wishes, but it does cater for use of themes and lexers — but still loads very, very fast (on my 2015 MacBook, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

**FWIW**,
I've *recently* started using "**[Brackets](http://brackets.io/)**" on Mac OS, and find it suits *my* specific needs & usecase well; it takes ~ 5-7 seconds to open on Mac OS 10.12.6 (Sierra) on an old 2011 MBP, 2.5 GHz i7, 16gb RAM.

On a newer machine...

Answer (score 0):

Use Nano/Pico from the terminal. Opens in less than a second and you can use it remotely through SSH.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new editor for OSX which is much different than everything out there. [Feather](https://www.feathereditor.com) is a "vim-like" editor that can open files instantly with constant memory consumption. You can basically open any file with ~ 10-20MB of memory consumption. Also it comes with some nice features, definitely recommended.